# Creating correlation matrix p values

Tags: r

I can get correlation matrix using following commands:

```
> df<-data.frame(x=c(5,6,5,9,4,2,1,3,5,7),y=c(3.1,2.5,3.8,5.4,6.5,2.5,1.5,8.1,7.1,6.1),z=c(5,6,4,9,2,4,1,6,2,4))
> cor(df)
           x         y        z
x  1.0000000 0.2923939 0.6566866
y  0.2923939 1.0000000 0.1167084
z 0.6566866 0.1167084 1.0000000
>
```

I can get individual p-values using command:

```
> cor.test(x,y)$p.value
[1] 0.4123234
```

How can I get a matrix of p-values for all these correlation coefficients? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can also use the package `Hmisc`.

An example of how it works:

```
mycor <- rcorr(as.matrix(data), type="pearson")
```

`mycor$r` shows the correlation matrix, `mycor$p` the matrix with corresponding p-values.

Comment: As 'cor' itself is a function, there was some confusion to me. I am using 'mycor = rcorr(......)' and I can easily get r, n and P values from mycor. Thanks.

Comment: Use `cor$P`.... with capital P

Answer (score 4):

This example calculates the p value for each of the column combinations. It is not an optimal solution (`x-y` and `y-x` p values are both calculated for example), but should provide some inspiration for you. The main trick is to use `expand.grid` to generate the combinations of columns, and use `mapply` to call `cor.test` on each combination:

```
col_combinations = expand.grid(names(df), names(df))
cor_test_wrapper = function(col_name1, col_name2, data_frame) {
    cor.test(data_frame[[col_name1]], data_frame[[col_name2]])$p.value
}
p_vals = mapply(cor_test_wrapper, 
                  col_name1 = col_combinations[[1]], 
                  col_name2 = col_combinations[[2]], 
                  MoreArgs = list(data_frame = df))
matrix(p_vals, 3, 3, dimnames = list(names(df), names(df)))
           x         y          z
x 0.00000000 0.4123234 0.03914453
y 0.41232343 0.0000000 0.74814951
z 0.03914453 0.7481495 0.00000000
```

Comment: Thanks but I am still trying to understand *apply functions.

Answer (score 2):

one way is to use `corr.test` (notice the double r) from package `psych`

.. or if you're a fan of `mapply` and `sapply` you could write your own function doing this. something like:

```
rrapply <- function(A, FUN, ...) mapply(function(a, B) lapply(B, 
         function(x) FUN(a, x, ...)), a = A, MoreArgs = list(B = A))
cor.tests <- rrapply(df, cor.test) # a matrix of cor.tests
apply(cor.tests, 1:2, function(x) x[[1]]$p.value) # and it's there
```

And now you can use the same logic to make a matrix of t-tests or, say, CI's of correlations

Comment: Thanks but using rcorr seems easier to beginners like me.